# Imaging XBOX 360 Profile USB Flash Drive

Tags: xbox-360

My XBOX 360 internal drive is dead. And I use 16GB Kingston USB Flash Drive as profile.

Temporarily I need that 16GB Flash Drive.

I need to back up the 16GB Drive on my Windows 10. Delete the contents of the 16GB drive, reformat it and use it on Linux.

After I am done, I need to restore my XBOX profile from Windows 10 and use that 16gb usb drive back to XBOX 360.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download a tool such as USBXTAFGUI, Horizon, Modio to backup your profile.

Links here:

USBXTAFGUI - https://mega.nz/#!BQFBVZ6S!7Fq-rjwA7hXpJxiB_kHeU1Tr4uA1v2BsTftnjR5tMSI

Horizon - https://www.wemod.com/horizon

Modio - https://modio.en.uptodown.com/windows